# result to be displayed in single column

Tags: postgresql

I am working on PostgreSQL, below is my query which returns min and max dates from the table based on the condition.

```
select   min(created_date),
         max(created_date) 
from     myTable 
where    mode='auto' 
and      status='released' 
group by mode;
```

Result:

```
min          max
date         date

2012-01-15   2016-11-24
```

`created_date` is of type date.I want the result to be displayed in single column as below.

```
created_date
date

2012-01-15
2016-11-24
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UNION or UNION ALL:

```
select   min(created_date),
from     myTable 
where    mode='auto' 
and      status='released' 
group by mode
UNION ALL
select   max(created_date) 
from     myTable 
where    mode='auto' 
and      status='released' 
group by mode;
```